# spring security tiles thymeleaf page Not Found 404

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, tiles, thymeleaf

i have configured spring mvc and theymeleaf and tiles and its working fine ,now i am trying to integrate spring security with them
 
**but the problem are:**
**1.when the application starts at login page and inputting the username and password no response (i.e) its never call the controller (i have used  `System.out.println("calling");` but nothing printed inside the login method)

2.When i try to access another page its redirecting to the login page but cant find it and give 404 not found**
can any body tell where i am going wrong in my configuration?

**Spring-Servlet**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.gaca.gms.controllers" />

    <bean id="templateResolver" 
                class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
                <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
                <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    </bean>

        <bean id="tilesConfigurer" 
                class="org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.spring4.web.configurer.ThymeleafTilesConfigurer">
                <property name="definitions">
                        <list>
                                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</value>
                        </list>
                </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
                <property name="viewClass" 
                        value="org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.spring4.web.view.ThymeleafTilesView" />
                <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
                <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
                <property name="order" value="1" />
                <property name="viewNames" value="templates/*,pages/*,redirect*,loginView" />
        </bean> 
        <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
                <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
                <property name="additionalDialects">
                        <set>
                                <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.dialect.TilesDialect" />
                                 <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
                        </set>
                </property>
        </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> -->
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="usersService" class="org.gaca.gms.services.GenericServiceImpl"></bean>
    <!-- <bean id="loginService" class="org.gaca.gms.services.GenericServiceImpl"></bean> -->
    <bean id="genericDAO" class="org.gaca.gms.dao.GenericDAOImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="loginController"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController">
    <property name="viewName" value="loginView" />
   </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

**Tiles-defs**

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="layout" template="templates/layout" templateType="thymeleaf">
        <put-attribute name="header"   value="templates/header" type="thymeleaf" />
        <put-attribute name="menu"   value="templates/menu" type="thymeleaf" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="templates/footer"  type="thymeleaf"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" />

    </definition>
    <definition name="loginView" extends="layout">
        <put-attribute name="body"   value="login.html" type="thymeleaf" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="pages/usersView" extends="layout">
        <put-attribute name="body"   value="pages/users" type="thymeleaf" />
    </definition>
     <definition name="pages/sendView" extends="layout">
        <put-attribute name="body"   value="pages/sendMessage" type="thymeleaf" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

**Spring-Security**

```
 <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

      <http pattern="/loginView" security="none"/>

    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/templates/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/**" access="hasAuthority('User')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/admin/**" access="hasRole('Admin')"/>

          <form-login login-page="/loginView" authentication-failure-url="/loginView" default-target-url="/pages/usersView" always-use-default-target='true'/>

        <remember-me />
  </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
              <user name="admin" password="123" authorities="Admin,User" />
              <user name="user" password="111" authorities="User" />
             </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

**LoginController**

```
@RequestMapping("/spring_security_login")
    public String login() {
        System.out.println("calling login");
        return "loginView";
    }

   // Login form with error
    @RequestMapping("/spring_security_login")
    public String loginError(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("loginError", true);
        return "loginView";
    }
```

**LoginPage**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <div sec:authentication="name"/> 

        <h1>Login page</h1>
        <p th:if="${loginError}">Wrong user or password</p>
        <form th:action="@{/j_spring_security_check}" method="post">
            <label for="j_username">Username</label>:
            <input type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username" /> <br />
            <label for="j_password">Password</label>:
            <input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password" /> <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: From your Spring Security setup, it looks like you are using `/loginView` as the login page, but your Controller is defining `/spring_security_login`.  Shouldn't those match up?

Comment: @CodeChimp i did try it as u commented but nothing change

Comment: Can you put print outs in your Controller to see if it's getting that far?  I think you'll find it's not.

Comment: @CodeChimp yes i did as i said in my question its doesn't call the controller

Comment: In this example, they only have one `<html>` tag and the permissions are set to `permitAll`:  http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/02/15/xml-config-based-method-level-spring-security-using-protect-pointcut/